# Profile Link Sharing in Facebook and Twitter

Tags: javascript, dom-events, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following JavaScript code for sharing the link in Facebook and Twitter....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function show_fb(id)
 {

 alert('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
 http://devel.testingsite.biz/testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile&id='+id+'');

 u=location.href;
 t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={https_server}testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile&id='+id+'','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
return false;
}
 </script>
```

On the HTML side its shown as such:

```
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_fb({uid});" class="icon_h3"></a></li>
```

Well the function is working and it shows the share window, but the link I got to share is the one without id

http://devel.testingsite.biz/testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile

But the same link when printed in alert function shows the id(as shown below).I need to produce the following link.

http://devel.testingsite.biz/testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile&id=645

Is there any mistake in my function?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function show_fb(id)
 {

 alert("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
 http://devel.testingsite.biz/testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile&id='+id+'");

 u=location.href;
 t=document.title;
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={https_server}testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile&id='+id+'','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436");
return false;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={https_server}testxxxxx.php?cmd=profile&id='+id+','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436");